# Editable Table with Jquery in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want make editable table in asp.net core 2.1 for my study project but I stil never use jquery.Can somedy help me.The table must be inline editable and for button view I need to get all data for current row and present to another view 
               `enter code here`
        Users List
        
            
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Username
                        Email
                        First Name
                        Last Name
                        Birthday
                        Role
                        Image
                        Is Active
                        Remove

```
                @foreach (var user in Model)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.UserName</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.Email</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.FirstName</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.LastName</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.DateOfBirth</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">@user.UserRole</td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">
                            <img src="@user.Image" width="30" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="pt-3-half">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@user.IsActive"
                                   id="isActive" checked disabled>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button a type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                                    asp-action="Edit">
                                EDIT
                            </button>
                            <button a type="button" id="view" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                                    asp-action="UserView">
                                EDIT
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have problem in making it editable or collecting the data?

Comment: I can collect but with c#  and this will be take too much but Iwant make simple.With this inline edit I realy dont understand how.

Comment: Do you want to collect the data on server-side or client-side? I'm sorry, I do not understand what the problem actually is.